# HTML anchor and input buttons with same CSS style, but different dimensions

Tags: html, css, button

So I have a basic button class that applies the same styling to various buttons across a site.

I have had to end up putting a form input, and an anchor tag next to each other, and their height and width is different. I have made the inner button text the same on each one just to show the differences like for like (obviously I dont need 2 'Add' buttons next to each other :P)

I dont want to specify the width, or the height in the CSS as the contents will change. Even the font looks slightly different sized, and from the box model it looks like the padding is alright.

http://jsfiddle.net/aeD4Z/2/

Markup

```
<form id="" method="POST" action="">
<input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<a class="button" href="">Add</a>
```

CSS

```
.button {
    font-family: Arial;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FCB97E 0%, #F07605 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #F07605;
    border-radius: 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em 0.5em;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 13px;
    outline: medium none;
    padding: 5px 8px !important;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

***EDIT:*** As you can see below it is not the padding, as the box models in firebug show the padding is the same for each one, so its something todo with the actual element itself

[image: Box model for input and anchor]

How do I get both to be the same dimensions from a single CSS class in my js fiddle above?

Comment: When you inspect the element with Firebug or something similar you will also get the default styles the browser set on the elements. Maybe you will find the difference there.

Comment: What browser is this happening in? I'm not seeing on issues in Chrome except for a different margin.

Comment: chrome and FF are both showing differences in height, although FF is a lot bigger difference

Comment: Have you tried `box-sizing: border-box;`? I realise this was asked a long while back, but it often solves the issue of different sizes despite the same styles.

Comment: For me, `box-sizing` wasn't the issue. The UA stylesheet set `input, textarea, keygen, select, button`'s `line-height` to `normal` whereas a reset stylesheet set `font` to `inherit` on several elements (including `a` but excluding `button`); `font` has a shorthand for `line-height`. Then it set `line-height: 1` on `body`. Thus, my `button` had a `line-height: normal` and my `a` had a `line-height: 16px`. Inspection looked similar to the pictures: identical padding & border but content "somehow" bigger.

Comment: I have run the same snippet (https://jsfiddle.net/u7xdxpx5/) on both Chrome and Firefox (running on Ubuntu) and found the exact same result: perfect matching. What is your browser version, is it up-to-date? I changed your code to cross-compare and monospace. here's a pic: https://pasteboard.co/H2sh2Sk.png

Answer (score 5):

To fully equalize „button-ish“ `<a>` anchors, `input` and more recently `button`, it is a good idea, to synchronize their box-sizings:

`input` and `button` for historical reasons are still in quirks mode (resp. already in modern mode [`box-sizing: border-box`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)) the rest is in [`box-sizing: content-box`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) mode...  (either way: gotta put in the same mode or compensate for equal heights by differenciating padding)

[image]

**This is my standard “test”, when I start styling for a site:**

```
__AA__
<button id='button'>plain Button</button>
<a class='button' href='#'>plain Anchor</a>
<a class='button'>linkless Anchor</a>
<input class='button' type='submit' value='Input Button' />
__BB__
```

**this CSS (in [stylus](http://stylus-lang.com/) notation) is a good boilerplate:**

```
button, a.button, input.button
    display inline-block
    font-size 12px
    font-weight bold

    color white
    font-family sans-serif
    text-decoration none
    background #24B345
    cursor pointer // also linkless (i.e. js) anchors/buttons should have that

    // important to equalize input/button vs. anchor:
    box-sizing content-box
    border 4px solid green
    padding 8px 10px
    margin 5px 4px 10px 0

    // some of this is default, 
    // but since input often gets styled elsewhere...
    vertical-align middle // a bit subject to taste 
    min-height 0 

    &:hover, &:focus // slight hover effect, resp. keyboard use (:focus)
         background: #44D365
```

[Live on Codefork](https://codepen.io/fnocke/pen/rjXZGB?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

The padding applies differently to the button and anchor.  I don't know this as fact, but my guess is a button reserves a little more space around it's value to look more like a button where a link is rendered as text.

You might try this:

```
a {
   padding-top:5px !important;
   padding-bottom:5px !important;
   padding-left:0px !important;
   padding-right:0px !important;
}
```

Which won't be exactly the same size, but pretty close.

Comment: as stated originally in the post I dont think its padding. the box models shown in my update show this (the purple) where as the blue part seems to be bigger than it needs to be on the input

Comment: I still think it boils down to trying to style text to look like a button which has certain overhead associated with it.  The quick and easy would be to put put a button styled button inside an anchor without styling the anchor like a button...  http://jsfiddle.net/aeD4Z/3/  However that might not be what you are looking for.

Comment: Chiming in to say I'm having the same problem. Padding is the same on both (verified, can see it), but height is probably twice as high on the anchor as on the input. So weird!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I always add line-height property in button class, like this:

```
/* HTML */
<a href="" class="button"> Go somewhere </a>

<button class="button"> Click here </button>

<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
```

```
/* CSS */
.button {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    line-height: inherit;   // this property does magic
   // rest of the styling
}
```

And this always work for me..